# Comparsion of CouchDB vs MongoDB Regarding CAP(Consistancy,Availability,Partition) Principle

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I have been confused by different answers of couchDB and MongoDB (e.g http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/08/04/mongodb-vs-couchdb.html this blog tells that MongoDB is CP and CouchDB is AP)
,however this answer [When to use CouchDB over MongoDB and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437790/when-to-use-couchdb-over-mongodb-and-vice-versa) tells that  Mongo DB is AP and CouchDB is CP)

can Anyone please solve my confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/consistency.html

[image: Showing where CouchDB lay on the CAP triangle]

I think the confusion might come from the fact that you can talk about couchDB as a single node and as couchDB as a cluster of nodes. When you're working with couchDB as a single node it will be consistent, but that is true for MongoDB as well. But when you work with couchDB as a cluster consistency is the first to go, you might get different versions of the document depending on which node you request it from.